# Python Kivy open web browser

Tags: python, browser, web, hyperlink, kivy

I've seen a similar topic last year, but it didn't provided the right solution. What I need is to create a hyperlink in Kivy, not only for Android, but also for iOS. Is there any way to do such thing?

Comment: See the bottom of this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/9sH0y3KxCuU